# Compare "similar" numbers in Python

Tags: python, math, rounding

In order to sync my iPod and my local music repository, I created a unique key for each track using its metadata. The unique track consists of the track's following metadata fields:
artist, album, track number, duration. The iPod saves the track's duration in milliseconds, but my local repository saves it in seconds. For example: 437590 milliseconds on iPod is 438 seconds in my Local repository.

When I divide the ipod's track duration by 1000 I get 437. I tried using `round()`, but `round (b.tracklen/1000)` prints `437`.

I can hack this by checking `math.ceil()`, `math.floor()` for the iPod duration if there is no match but it's a lousy solution.

What is the best approach to this issue?

Comment: Sounds to me like you just need to use a threshold. Something like `if abs(numA - numB) < thresh: everything_looks_good();`

Comment: Try: `round(b.tracklen/1000.0)`

Comment: @kwatford is right for Python 2 - you need floating point division. For Python 3, this problem won't happen - the semantics of division has changed, and there is a new `//` operator for integer division.

Comment: Actually, after trying the round options I still have some missing songs which I couldn't track down. so I'm now implementing the math.floor() and math.ceil() and I'll soon see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `round` call is giving the wrong result as you're dividing by 1000, instead of 1000.0

```
>>> round(437590/1000.0)
438.0
```

Comment: thanks, that's solved the issue. is there any reference available on this ? I've read round() in the documentation but I don't remember notes on something similar

Comment: @Liron - that's because your issue is the semantics of the division operator. What `round` sees isn't the division computation, only the result, which (for integer division) is already truncated to 437. Round 437 to the nearest whole number and you get 437.

Comment: Also note that this is only true for Python2 and in Python3 luckily the semantics of the division have changed, which makes this a non issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are experiencing Python 2's *integer division*. When you divide two integers, Python (and many other languages) throw away the remainder. You'll want to divide by a float instead of an integer, as Dogbert indicated.

Comment: If you say "Python 2", I'll +1 - Python 3 behaves differently. Not a change I approve of, as it happens - I don't much care how a particular language chooses to handle division of integers, but I *do* care when a language changes the semantics of a basic arithmetic operator. Still, it's done now, and it *does* avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: Okay, thanks, good to know; changed it. Yeah, they did some controversial things in 3.

Comment: @Steve314 It was never a clever idea to use integer division in a dynamically typed language as a general rule, because it leads to exactly this kind of problems. And the 2to3 transition tool takes care of it for existing code.

Comment: @Voo - some people expect what you say. Some people expect an integer divided by an integer to give an integer - arithmetic operators returning the same type as their arguments. A *lot* of languages use that latter convention, so newbies are probably going to have to learn it at some point. There's even a math (abstract algebra) argument that it's exactly the right thing to do. Overall, it's swings and roundabouts, but changing semantics of division around two decades into the life of a language is still a bit crazy, however well it's managed. Not everyone will know to run that tool.

Answer (score 0):

Rounding the result of an integer division is very easy: `(n+(d/2))/d`. In your case:

```
def RoundedDivide(value, divisor):
    return (value + (divisor/2)) / divisor

>>> RoundedDivide(437590, 1000)
438
```

Comment: Is there anybody out there who can explain the downvote? I thought this answered the question directly, while avoiding all the problems that can be encountered with floating point numbers.

Comment: @hop, are you aware of a simpler way to do integer division with rounding? Please share.

Comment: this would be a fine answer… to another question.

Comment: @hop, how is it not relevant? The question states that `round` didn't give the answer they were looking for, and I provided a version that does. It will do so with a higher degree of confidence than the accepted answer, because it's not subject to the representation errors of floating point numbers.

Comment: +1 for a solution (which does solve the problem) which is different and worth considering.

Answer (score -2):

Honestly, I think you nailed it already with the floor and ceil calls, but for somplicity you might want to do floor((ipodtime/1000)+1) == localrepostime to check equality since the ipod time seems to round down no matter what.